# including perl module in a different directory in a single location which can be used for multiple files

Tags: perl

Let me describe my question.

I have created a new perl module 
ex:

Module : sample/lib/module/sample.pm

setenv SAMPLE /local/username/sample

I am using this module in multiple files and am using

use lib "$ENV{'SAMPLE'}/lib";

in each and every file i am using the module.

Is there a better solution ? instead of adding in each and every file the lib location to search for.

I tried adding it in the main script which calls other scripts but it doesn't work. I get the error lib not found  @INC.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically three ways to manipulate Perl's `@INC` variable (which is what you're trying to do here).

1. You can use `use lib` within your program. This is probably the best approach, but it can lead to having to edit a lot of files (as you've worked out).
2. You can use the `-I` command line option (either when you're calling Perl or on your shebang line). I've rarely seen this approach used.
3. You can set the `PERL5LIB` environment variable to a colon-separated list of directories. This means that you avoid having to hard-code the directory into every file, but you need to be sure that the environment is set up correctly before you execute your program.

I think that in your situation, I'd be looking at option 3.

Comment: Thanks Dave for your answer. I will try this out.